# itext7 in vb.net - Stamp rotated text on top of existing content

Tags: vb.net, itext7

I have this code which places rotated text where I want it on a pdf:

```
 Public Sub edit_existing_pdf(inpdf As String, outpdf As String)

        Dim pdf As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(inpdf), New PdfWriter(outpdf))

        Dim document As New Document(pdf)

        document.ShowTextAligned("This is some test text", 400, 750, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0.5F * CSng(Math.PI))

        document.Close()

    End Sub
```

It works fine on a 'blank' pdf, but it won't show when stamping on a pdf with existing content.

How can I set it to be 'over' stamped rather then 'under'?

Comment: *"How can I set it to be 'over' stamped rather then 'under'?"* - Stamping 'over' is the default, so you most likely run into a different issue. Maybe it's because you give absolute coordinates (`400, 750`) as each existing page may have its own coordinate system. Maybe it's some other issue. Can you share a representative example PDF to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The pdf I'm trying to stamp is confidential, so unfortunately I can't share that but I'll try to replicate the problem on another 'populated' pdf and upload it. The co-ords system is a good idea I hadn't thought of - I'll try some different values and see if I my text starts appearing. Maybe it's going off the side at the moment.

Comment: Hi - you were right about the coords, but the text isn't going off the page, it's stamping onto the last page (page 3 of 3) and I didn't notice this as I expected it to be on page 1 - my silly mistake. So my next question is: how do I control which page the text is being stamped on?

Comment: If you want to stamp a specific page, not the last one, there is another overload of `document.ShowTextAligned` that has an additional `page` parameter after the coordinate parameters. Remember, page numbers start with 1 in iText, not with 0.

Comment: Thanks - looks like when you add the page num though, it expects a paragraph instead of a string?

Comment: Yes. The string overloads actually call a paragraph overload underneath using `new Paragraph(text).setMultipliedLeading(1).setMargin(0)`. But there indeed is no string overload with a page parameter.

Comment: OK that works, I think we can call this solved and thanks VERY much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final line of code as per mkl's help:

```
document.ShowTextAligned(New Paragraph("This is some test text").SetMultipliedLeading(1).SetMargin(0), 400, 750, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0.5F * CSng(Math.PI))
```